# Substituição para a Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, fluent-api

Estou em um projeto de um sistema que utiliza a linguagem C#, usando MVC, Entity Framework e estou usando a Fluent API. Gostaria de saber se tem outra forma de fazer isso.

```
HasKey(oc => oc.OrdemCompraId);

HasRequired(oc => oc.UsuarioCadastro)
   .WithMany(oc => oc.OrdemCompraCadastrados)
   .HasForeignKey(oc => oc.UsuarioCadastroId);

HasOptional(oc => oc.UsuarioLiberacao)
   .WithMany(oc => oc.OrdemCompraCadastrados)
   .HasForeignKey(oc => oc.UsuarioLiberacaoId);

Property(oc => oc.Prioridade)
   .IsRequired();

HasRequired(oc => oc.Filial)
    .WithMany(oc => oc.OrdemCompras)
    .HasForeignKey(oc => oc.FilialId);
```

Comment: Coloque alguns exemplos que produzo uma resposta não muito ampla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estou supondo que a entidade se chama `OrdemCompra`:

```
public class OrdemCompra
{
    ...
    public int UsuarioCadastroId { get; set;}

    ...
    public virtual Usuario UsuarioCadastro { get; set; }
}
```

E em `Usuario`:

```
public class Usuario
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<OrdemCompra> OrdemCompraCadastrados { get; set; }
}
```

Só que, como você está mapeando várias cardinalidades 1 para N envolvendo `Usuario` e `OrdemCompra`, não tem como fugir completamente da *Fluent API*. Precisaria ter:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<OrdemCompra>()
                .HasRequired(oc => oc.UsuarioCadastro)
                .WithMany(u => u.OrdemCompraCadastrados)
                .HasForeignKey(oc => oc.UsuarioCadastroId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

No final, fica assim:

```
public class OrdemCompra
{
    ...
    public int UsuarioCadastroId { get; set; }
    public int UsuarioLiberacaoId { get; set; }

    ...
    public virtual Usuario UsuarioCadastro { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario UsuarioLiberacao { get; set; }
}

public class Usuario
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<OrdemCompra> OrdemCompraCadastrados { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrdemCompra> OrdemCompraLiberados { get; set; }
}
```

E o mapeamento:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<OrdemCompra>()
                .HasRequired(oc => oc.UsuarioCadastro)
                .WithMany(u => u.OrdemCompraCadastrados)
                .HasForeignKey(oc => oc.UsuarioCadastroId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<OrdemCompra>()
                .HasRequired(oc => oc.UsuarioLiberacao)
                .WithMany(u => u.OrdemCompraLiberados)
                .HasForeignKey(oc => oc.UsuarioLiberacaoId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```